# Can one bound the minimal degree of a solution to an inhomogeneous linear equation?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, filtered-algebras

Suppose $A = \cup_{i\in \mathbb N} A_{\leq i}$ is a filtered algebra and $M = \cup_{i\in \mathbb N} M_{\leq i}$ a filtered $A$-module. In my case, I know $A$ to be Noetherian and $M$ to be finitely generated. I have a fixed element $a\in A$ and for various elements $m\in M$ I am interested in the equation $ax = m$ (of course solving for variable $x\in M$).

It might of course happen that $ax = m$ has no solutions, and it might happen that it has many solutions of arbitrarily large filtration. I would like to prove an a priori bound of the following form: if $m \in M_{\leq i}$, then, if there is a solution $x\in M$ to $ax = m$, then there is a solution $x\in M_{\leq j}$ for some $j$ depending on $i$ and $a$ (and $A$ and $M$) but not $m$.

I don't expect that this type of *a priori* bound on the filtration degree of a minimal solution will hold for arbitrary actions and modules. Are there specific properties of $A,M$ that might be checkable that would guarantee such bounds?

Comment: $A$ is commutative?

Comment: @YCor In my case no, but I was a bit vague in the wording, hoping to learn techniques for problems like this, so I'm open to accepting any answer that I learn from.